# Why this PHP snippet failed to match anything?

Tags: php, regex

```
var_dump(preg_match_all('/(job_show\.asp\?id=[0-9]*)">/s',':</font><a href="job_show.asp?id=42"',$match));

$hrefs = $match[1];
var_dump($hrefs);
```

Output is:

```
int(0)
array(0) {
}
```

It's supposed to match "job_show.asp?id=42"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your pattern has "> at the end and there is no "> at the end of the searched string.

Comment: You observation ability is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Question Mark Quantifier after the > and see if that starts to capture the data you're looking for.

```
/(job_show\.asp\?id=[0-9]*)">?/
```